# Пользовательский интерфейс в виде блок сxемы

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Как реализовать пользовательский интерфейс в виде блок схемы. Сам вид блок схемы будет строиться на основе полученных данных. Возможно ли такое реализовать с помощью WinForms или WPF. Вместо квадратов на таблице будут кнопки, а вот как нарисовать линии? И представить ее в таком виде как на картинке. Какую библиотеку посоветуете? Пишу на C#
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В `WPF` для это все есть.

Comment: В WinForms тоже все есть. Где-то даже готовый рабочий пример находил, вроде на CodePlex-е